# How to compile a complex file

Tags: macros, compiling, mac, sourcecode

I just would like to know what do I need and how I can compile a template given in this form on GitHub: https://github.com/tetrapharmakon/mycv. I am using TexShop on a Mac.

I am a beginner with LaTex, and I am able just to produce and compile very simple texts. I guess here the author went much further with this template.

Suggestions about references that can help me grasp this kind of complex documents are welcome.

Comment: just copy the files locally and run xelatex (not pdflatex) on `civi.tex` If you need more help, say what you did and what error you got. The structure is a very basic `article` class document as should be described in any tutorial

Comment: I ran xelatex, and got "error: option clash for packedge fontspec".

Comment: It's not at all uncommon for files found on the internet not to work. The error message will tell you what the clashing opton was and if you type `h` it sugests a fix, although I had a quick look and don't see where fontspec is loaded twice, the layout.tex just loads mathspec (which loads fontspec)

Comment: but I just tried civi.tex and layout.tex and theer is no option clash error  (I don't have the font bt that's a separate thing) I don't see how you can get an option clash from the code at that site.